# "Tastes great warm too!"

Tags: alimentation

I'm trying to translate the phrase "Tastes great warm too!" as for a drink that you can have warm as well as cold (think tea and iced tea). Someone suggested I use

> "Tout aussi bon chaud!"

Is that a good translation for what I am trying to convey? The language choice can be "youthful" but I want to avoid slang (especially since it needs to be properly understood in Quebec). If it is not a good translation what should I use instead?

Comment: As a francophone of Quebec, this is a correct translation. Another idea could be: ''C'est (or Ça goûte) bon, même chaud''!

Comment: @Archa "ca goute bon" may be correct in Quebec, but not in France.

Comment: You can express it as "tout aussi delicieux chaud que froid"/"aussi bon chaud que froid" . thats a bit different from your original idea but something that you can see on french products at the supermarket for example.

Comment: The [following advertising](http://cecemel.be/fr-BE/product/mager) uses the (very "advertising") sentence : "Toujours un délice, chaud ou froid". Could be a good inspiration in your case...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first idea is usable as it is. Let's see the possible variants :

(I assumed that in your case, the cold way is the normal way to have this beverage)

> Se consomme/boit également chaud *(rather neutral)*
>
> Peut aussi être consommé/bu/pris chaud *(a bit less formal than the first)*
>
> A essayer chaud / A essayer chaud *(slightly playful)*
>
> Servez-le froid ou... chaud ! *(playful)*

And if you don't need to be laconic, you can even introduce these with something like *Pour varier les plaisirs, ...*

(and I didn't want to "steal" Archa's suggestion in his/her comment, but it also seems a good variant to me)

Comment: J'aime particulièrement ta 4e proposition !

Answer (score 2):

Well, taking off from what we see on some drinks cans, *se boit frais ou chaud* ?

Comment: Good point here : depending on the beverage, *frais* can be prefered to *froid*, mostly because in french it not only means "cold" but also conveys a "freshness" connotation.